# Decoding special char with JS for DataLayerVariable

Tags: javascript, utf-8, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, htmlspecialchars

Fetching a component of a URL with some JS for use as a DLV in GTM/GA.

```
function() {
  var regex = /keyword\/(.*)/;
  if(regex.test({{Page Path}})) {
    return regex.exec({{Page Path}})[1];
  }
 return
}
```

This will retrieve the string value within a URL that contains '.../keyword/**this%test**/here/more/never-ends

My question -
What can I add to this function to decode the special characters?
This function passes the string value as a data layer element for use in GTM/GA; but I would like to see values sent without the encoded characters - i.e. %20 for spaces.

I've tried a few things but nothing seems to be working.

UPDATE!
Actually figured this out; I'm a newb..

```
function() {
  var regex = /keyword\/(.*)/;
  if(regex.test({{Page Path}})) {
    return **decodeURIComponent(regex.exec({{Page Path}})[1]);**
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, worth noting, you are capturing everything after keyword, not sure if you want to only include the first group after, if so, you need to add another `\/` before the last `/`. You can also call exec first, and if the result is not null, grab the value of [1] to save one the processing time of the test fx

Comment: Thanks Carl!
One more question..
What if the url does not end with a '/'
Example:
https://www.example.com/keyword/test
My regex above is showing undefined/null.
Is there a change to the regex that will account for 'both instances' - when there's no '/' and when there is a '/'?

Comment: More specifically, this will not work for URLs that do not have a trailing hash '/'

It's also being 'rejected' by GTM (google tag manager)


    function() {
      var regex = /keyword\/(.*)\//;
      if(regex.test({{Page Path}})) {
        return **decodeURIComponent(regex.exec({{Page Path}})[1]);**
      }
    }